# Unable to click on 'Cancel' button

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver

I'm writing automated script using Selenium WebDriver with Ruby. In the case, I've to click on 'Cancel' button and following is the html code for it:

```
<div class="ui-dialog-buttonset">
 <button class="otherButtonClass" type="button" role="button" aria-disabled="false">
  <span class="ui-button-text">Rename</span>
 </button>
 <button class="cancelButtonClass" type="button" role="button" aria-disabled="false">
  <span class="ui-button-text">Cancel</span>
 </button>
</div>
```

For clicking on 'Cancel' button, I wrote following:

```
driver.find_element(:xpath, "//button[@class='cancelButtonClass']").click
```

here click action doesn't happen. I tried sleep, wait.until { element.displayed? } still issue wasn't resolved. The error thrown is 'Element is not visible and hence may not be interacted with'

However, if I perform click action on 'Rename' button, it works:

```
driver.find_element(:xpath, "//button[@class='otherButtonClass']").click
```

Please help me to understand why this is happening. I'm confused, 'Rename' and 'Cancel' have similar html code and still clicking on 'Rename' passes and clicking on 'Cancel' fails. Why like this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below :

```
script = <<-end
element = arguments[0];
element.setAttribute('aria-disabled','true');
return element;
end

# select the 'Cancel' button element
elem = driver.find_element(:css,'div.ui-dialog-buttonset>button')[1]
# setting the 'aria-disabled' to true
elem = driver.execute_script(script,elem)
#after enabling the css attribute 'aria-disabled' click on the
#cancel button
elem.click
```

Answer (score 0):

Using CSS selection will not be a perfect solution in case if the Button CSS are dynamic for any hover actions. Also the Simple way of selecting given element is using the following xpath.

```
driver.find_element(:xpath, "//span[text()='Cancel']").click
```

Comment: Yes,I do agree, i suggested the solution only if the CSS of the button is dynamic.